# Point Cloudflare DNS to AWS Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudflare, amazon-route53, cloud-hosting

I want to point my DNS from **cloudflare to AWS Route 53.**
What i did was deleted all the records and added **NS Record**

```
ns-1579.awsdns-05.co.uk
ns-880.awsdns-46.net
ns-1425.awsdns-50.org
ns-176.awsdns-22.com
```

But it is not resolved. Can't figure out whats wrong.

Answer (score 3):

To use CloudFlare you'll need to use CloudFlare name servers only -- all other name servers for your domain would need to be removed at your domain registrar. If you happen to be using a CNAME setup with CloudFlare (business plan and above) you could continue to use Amazon Route 53, but you wouldn't be using CloudFlare for DNS in addition to Route 53 for DNS ...you'd use one or the other.